# Mark SharePoint custom workflow completed if any one of the tasks is complete

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I have a requirement to create a workflow where users are in AD group. Condition is:
- the task should go to two users of that AD group and if any one of them approves it should mark workflow as completed.

I created a Sequential WF (VS) as I couldnt retrieve the AD users in designer. I managed to create two parallel tasks using replicator activity but I am not able to mark workfliw as completed when any of the user approves. As there are two tasks workflow waits for the other user to take an action and shows the status as 'In Progress' until both approves. I know this is the default behaviour but I want to stop it at first approval.

Please suggest me something that will help me meet the deadline. Please 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom SharePoint group and assign anyone to it. With your workflow just set the if statement to go through its happy path when someone from your AD group has set it as approved. If out of the box approval workflow doesn't fit your needs you can create a choice column (preferably hidden) and set the default to NULL.  Then when the AD user marks the task it goes down either an APPROVED or NOT_APPROVED path.